# Application startup failed - Failed to process import candidates for configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm receiving this error in the stack trace when I try to run:

```
java -jar spring-boot-starter-web.jar
```

From my command line on my build for my jar of my Spring Boot application. I'm not sure what is causing this error. I let IntelliJ do the build of the project.

> [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application
>   startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed
>   to process import candidates for configuration class
>   [app.ContactRunner]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes
>   found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom
>   packaging, make sure that file is correct.

For reference, the ContactRunner class is just:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ContactRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(ContactRunner.class, args);
  }
}
```

The `spring-boot-starter-parent` is in the `pom.xml` as well as the one for the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` as other people with similar questions have resolved their issue with it. I can't figure out what's happening. Here is my full pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Output to jar format -->
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starters</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>NameProject</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Boot Web Starter</name>
    <description>Starter for building web, including RESTful, applications using Spring
        MVC. Uses Tomcat as the default embedded container
    </description>
    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA Data (for using Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                                <mainClass>
                                    app.ContactRunner
                                </mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I also tried to build the project with `mvn clean package` but it fails because of duplicate dependencies that I can't seem to remove, as you may see my issues in this questions, so this was trying another route.

Any ideas? The application runs fine in IntelliJ, but won't with a jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `spring-boot-starter-parent` in parent tag. And should remove whole `dependencyManagement` block.

Comment: Gave this a shot, but it's saying  the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: Is your package structure correct. Means  `@SpringBootApplication` class should be in top package.

Comment: For example, let's your class @SpringBootApplication is inside a package a.b.c then all other spring stereotype classes should goes inside a.b.c.x

Comment: Yep! That's how they are laid out. The main class is in `/src/main/java/app` the rest of the classes of the whole project are also in this directory, but in sub-packages from here, like `/src/main/java/app/controllers`. Does this class need to be one up in `src/main/java` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not changing anything, still have the same issue.

Comment: One more thing, I think you dont require spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency.

Comment: When trying to run the jar, it can't find the main manifest attribute if I put it my main class in `src/main/java` (not in any package). 

I don't know why, but i suspect there's an intelliJ bug occurring. IT wouldn't register the change of the location of that class when I moved it in the final .jar it would create. Your first suggestion in your answer fixed my Maven issues, and was able to build and run the program that way.